# Asynchronous Servlet processing in Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

Is there any way to make use of [Java EE Asynchronous Web Servlet processing](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) in Spring Web Flow? I see a fair amount about [Spring MVC support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async), but nothing about Web Flow. Where ideally I'd want only certain transitions or actions to use the approach.

Would you have to use the `DeferredResult` approach? Although that *seems* to be intended for doing the work somewhere unaware of the web container context, which Web Flow isn't.

I can get the native `HttpServletRequest`, of course, and from there call:

```java
AsyncContext acontext = startAsync();
```

But since Web Flow isn't dealing with low level HTTP request/response objects, I don't know how I'd tie the two together.

I'd love to see a working example. I'm hoping I don't have to exit Web Flow in order to do the Asynchronous request processing.

Comment: I am having a really hard time thinking about how that would work with webflow. Exiting the flow, like we do often times for reports, seems more likely.
What would be a good use case for this within a flow?

Comment: Really, just anything that waits long enough for completion that you don’t want to block a web container thread. In this case, a multi-step process that culminates in a web service call to a partner system, where they want us to “poll” for something that can take a fair amount of time to complete. But that needs to cause flow things to occur after completion (or failure).

Comment: I think you'll have to do it outside of webflow. I'd be interested if you find a way to do it though

Comment: I opened a Jira issue to request this (or guidance on it) as well: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1743